Supress jenkins's prompt build with parameters on loaded file
I have a jenkins pipeline, without a parameters. That pipeline is calling another pipeline with parameters using the module 'load'. I load a new file and run it. Is there a way to suppress jenkins from asking me to build with parameters when building the upstream pipeline, as that pipeline does not have any parameters?
In other words, i need jenkins to only ask for the parameters that the upstream job needs and the ones the loaded file needs.
I used the hide paramters plugin to override those parameters. But after the first run, it again asks for the parameters of the loaded file.

You may need to share your pipeline and your jenkins version because AFAIK Jenkins does not show parameters if none parameter is set.
